# Why might one evaluate `defined $x && $x` in boolean context?

Tags: perl, operators, boolean

```
my $target_type = (defined($item->{target_type}) && $item->{target_type}) 
                ? $item->{target_type} 
                : "";

my $target_id   = (defined($item->{target_id}) && $item->{target_id})
                ? $item->{target_id} 
                : "";
```

Why did the developer use `&&` with almost the same conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently he's the belt and suspenders type.  `(defined($x) && $x)` is almost equivalent to just `$x`, because `undef` is false.  (The difference is that if `$x` is `undef` then `(defined($x) && $x)` will be Perl's special false value, which is defined, but in this case that makes no difference.)  Possibly there used to be a different condition (like `$x > 0`) and the `defined` test was necessary to avoid a warning about an uninitialized value.  Then someone removed that condition and didn't think to remove the now-unnecessary `defined`.

Another reason for using `(defined($x) && $x)` (as [onon15 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12419305/8355)) is to emphasize to future maintenance programmers that `$x` might not be defined.  Personally, I would use a comment for that, but [TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

Comment: Another possibility is that the original coder (mistakenly) thought `if $item->{target_type}` would vivify the key.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the right-hand side of the && could be used by itself, I've seen such use many times as a semantic hint for the human reader, that `$item->{target_type}` might not be defined.

So even though one could remove the LHS and remain with similar behavior, a maintainer might then be easily mistaken to think that no checks of whether the value is defined are necessary. (unless in a tight loop, the cost of that extra evaluation is negligible, and even inside a loop it is likely to be removed by optimizations in the interpreter).

Answer (score 2):

Extremely short answer: It's to avoid the "Use of uninitialized value" warning in older perls and to assign a default defined value in that case. In v5.10 and later, you'd use the defined-or operator:

```
 $scalar //= "";
```

Comment: I see, I got it now, the company I work with is still using Perl 5.8 and the code is very old.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is a "logical short circuit" operator.  First he's testing definedness of `$item->{targ_type}`.  If, and only if it is defined (ie, the left side of the `&&` is true) then he tests to see whether `$item->{target_type}` contains a true value.  If both conditions are true, then `$target_type` (and later `$target_id`) get assigned the value held in `$item->{target_type}` or `$item->{target_id}`.  If one of those conditions is false, then an empty string is assigned.

Update: To attempt to read the mind of the programmer who came up with the construct: Perhaps the code evolved in a way that led to this, and the programmer didn't think about it long enough to recognize that it's unnecessary.  Perhaps the programmer is insecure about the distinction between definedness, truth, falsehood, and what types of values are "false" in Perl.

Comment: While the words in the answer are true, I don't see that they answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question entails mind reading, but here are a few reasons sorted by probability:

1. The author was not a Perl programmer and was therefore uncomfortable with the truthiness of `undef`, the fact that `defined undef && undef` evaluates to `""` and makes the rest of the expression moot, or both.
2. The code has seen a revision which removed something that needed the `defined` test to work well, for example `defined $x && $x ne ''`.  The `defined` test is cruft left over from that edit, of negative value to maintainers.
3. The author wished to emphasize that the element might be `undef` and so tested for it explicitly.  There are better ways to do this, ones that don't leave future readers guessing what the intent might have been.  Like, say, comments.
4. If defined, `$item->{target_type}` might contain an object with an overloaded boolean conversion that is expensive to calculate and you're looking at a self-defeating micro-optimization.  This case is extremely unlikely.  Funny, though.

Comment: Actually `defined undef && undef` evaluates to Perl's canonical false value, which is a special empty string that evaluates to 0 in numeric context without the warning about a non-numeric value that a normal empty string would give.

Comment: @cjm: True, though I'm going to go out on a limb and say that the original author was not making sure he'd get warned if he ever used `$target_type` in numeric context.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the same condition.

First, he tests for definedness

```
defined($item->{target_type})
```

some operations make no sense when operating with undefined values.

In the second condition, he tests for a true or false value

```
$item->{target_type}
```

However, as `undef` is a false value, the second test covers both cases.

In some cases, a similar pattern is neccessary, e.g. when testing against the contents of a reference.

```
my $ref1 = "true";
my $ref2 = \("true");

if (ref $ref1 eq 'SCALAR' and $$ref1) {
  # This does not get executed
}
if (ref $ref2 eq 'SCALAR' and $$ref2) {
  # This does get executed
}
```